# Finding the magnitude of a 3X1 complex vector in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, vector, complex-numbers, magnitude

I was wondering if someone would help me with this problem.
I have complex 3x1 matrix that looks like,

```
matrix = np.matrix([[(0.0009118819655545739+0.0009118819655545738j)], [(0.0009118819655544588-0.0009118819655544589j)], [(-0.0009118819655545161-5.421010862427522e-20j)]])
```

As I am not interested in the last element I will delete as follows, so I get:

```
vector = np.delete(matrix, 2, 0)
```

This gives me,

```
vector = [[(0.0009118819655545739+0.0009118819655545738j)]]
         [[(0.0009118819655544588-0.0009118819655544589j)]]
```

I am interested in finding the magnitude of the above vector (2X1). This is what I have done:

```
for element in vector:
      mag = np.absolute(element)
    
return mag
```

What I get is the,

```
mag = 0.0012895958429705512
```

which is the magnitude of the first element.

How do I get the magnitude of the new 2x1 vector that incorporates the complex values of all elements in the vector?

Is the math correct: if I consider,

```
vector = [[(x1+x2j)]]
         [[(y1-y2j)]]
```

As mag = sqrt((x1)**2 + (x2)**2 + (y1)**2 + (y2)**2))
which would instead give me a mag of 0.00182376392 rather than 0.0012895958429705512.

I would really appreciate the help with this problem.

Many thanks

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem: `np.matrix` is not recommended. You should use a regular `np.ndarray` instead. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.classes.html#matrix-objects

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why np.matrix is not recommended but np.ndarray?

Comment: The link in my previous comment provides an explanation

Answer (score 2):

numpy comes with `numpy.linalg.norm` for calculating the norm of a vector. c.f [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

In your case that would simply be:

```py
np.linalg.norm(vector)
```